# Back Transformation With Python

Tags: python

How can I code back transformation with Python? As I showed my code so how could I back transform it? I have used OLS Model and Least Square Method

`y=np.log10(y)`

Comment: what do you mean about `back transformation`?

Comment: Do you just need the inverse function of log10 (i.e., exponentiation)? If so, this is is simply `10**y`

Answer (score 0):

```
x
x2=log10(x)
x3= 10**x2
```

I believe this is what you're looking for